# Send commands to Serial using bash or Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, arduino, screen, tty

Im trying to send commands to a little Arduino type board. The board has a CP2012 Serial to USB adapter on board and is connected via Micro USB.

I can screen into it using

```
    screen -L /dev/cu.SLAB_USBtoUART 115200 -L
```

I have a script uploaded on it so that I can screen into it and then just type and press enter and that message is displayed on the mini display.
So every message send via Serial should show up on its screen.

I can use the Serial Monitor and just type it in and it works and I can use the screen command I wrote above to screen into it and then just type, hit enter and it shows up.

I tried it with this script to do it automatically like this:

```
    import serial
    import time

    ser = serial.Serial('/dev/cu.SLAB_USBtoUART', 115200, timeout = 1)
    commandToSend = "Hello there!"
    ser.write(str(commandToSend).encode())
```

Its not working. Nothing happens at first. If I then "log in" via screen I can see the "Hello there!" but it wasn't entered with an enter press.
How can I press enter after the "Hello there"?

```
    EDIT: \r carriage return works fine.
```

Only problem left to solve is this:

And I tried this, its also not working:

```
    sudo echo -en "Blub" >/dev/cu.SLAB_USBtoUART
```

Since it has a CP2012 on board and is connected via USB is it appropriate to still use import serial? Its technically not serial anymore its usb right?

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: if the upper one is solved by adding a carriage return you should add it to the lower example as well. most likely the code on the arduino waits for it but it's hard to tell without seeing the code  "Blub\r"

Comment: Just tried \r for the echo command it it doesn't work. Blub is literally just a world like hello or test etc its the noice a fish makes.
Every string I type in is displayed on a small display.

Comment: what about parameters for command line? baud rate... did you set it?   I also read that in some os echo -e might not work properly.